# Hide status bar for entire app

Tags: objective-c, ios

I create views programmatically. To hide status bar in view I use

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:NO];
```

in viewDidload method. The problem is every view have to implement the code above to be status bar hidden. Is there a way (programmatically) to set status bar hidden just in one place in the app so entire app to be without the status bar ?
I have tried to add this in AppDelegate, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open your app plist file `MyApp-Info.plist` and add a row with the `Status bar is initially hidden` and the `YES` value.

EDIT:

If you want to do it programmatically, add this in your `ApplicationDidFinishLaunching` :

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = YES;
```

Comment: Thanks, but my question is how to do that programmatically.

Comment: `ApplicationDidFinishLaunching` gets passed the`application` instance so you can just do `application.statusBarHidden = YES;`

Comment: also requires `View controller-based status bar appearance  NO ` on plist for the plist option to work

Comment: And if the status bar is not desired even at launch time, then what's needed on top of the above is to set `Status bar is initially hidden YES` on plist

Answer (score 2):

If you are targeting the devices with iOS > 3.2, then use the following code in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method in AppDelegate class.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
```

Answer (score 1):

just put key "Status bar is initially hidden" as YES in Info.plist file.
you will get hide status bar throughout the application.

If you want to do it by problematically, then just put this code in Appdelegate.m file of your project.

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating new views based on `UIView`, subclass `UIView` (we can call it `SummercView`) and add a `viewDidLoad` method to it that looks like:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:NO];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

And then in your xib or storyboard files, set the views where you want to hide the status bar to use `SummercView` instead of `UIView`.

And of course @Aadhira's answer is good, too.  +1 to him/her.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you create a view class which did this in viewDidLoad, and have your views be subclasses of it?  They'd still each have to hide the status bar, but at least you wouldn't have to duplicate the code in each subclass.