# make the top thing go away in modal segue

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

i have a modal segue , and the top thing that has like the bars and time for the iphone is annoying and i want it to go away, how do i do this? I tried messing with the attributes for the view controller, but none of them seems to help

Comment: I think I just answered your other question too? Try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053323/hide-status-bar-for-entire-app

Comment: cool man why didnt you use that as an answer i would check it!

Comment: Well it's not my answer. It's just courtesy to give credit to the real answerer you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean the status bar? You can hide it with this:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = YES;
```